# Within Drupal, POST to a script and redirect the user to it

Tags: php, drupal, post, http-post

I'm new to Drupal and dont know how to use it properly yet. I'm stuck on this part where I'm displaying links which when the user clicks on, I need the code to POST certain informaiton to that link and then redirect the user to that page.

1. User clicks on a link: [Enter Other Site]
2. System posts UserId, SecretPasswrod, etc to http://www.theotherside.com/handle.php
3. The User's browse is redirected to handle.php (whiuch redirects him elsewhere as appropriate)

I know how to do this in php (by creating a form on the page and then submitting it), but not sure how to do this 'properly' in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for how to do POST using PHP. I'm not familiar of any Drupal specific method, but this is how I'd do it:

- Create a module with a [menu hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) of name, say, mymodule-enter-other-site
- Define and create page callback function: in it, put the POST code you want using e.g. [HTTP POST from PHP example](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/)
  -- You may also want to define additional settings for permissions etc
- Make the link you want user to click to point to yourdomain.com/mymodule-enter-other-site
- Activate your module and give it a go

Should everything work as intended, page callback function is executed when user visits the address and you can build the data and finally redirect the user.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the HTTP POST from PHP example, Drupal has it's own process fot that: 
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it in Drupal

1) Use FORM API to create the form and then write your form submit code in form_submit function 
see http://drupal.org/node/751826

2) Use the webform module to create the form. see  http://drupal.org/project/webform

Comment: no - thats not it. i dont need to create a form on drupal at all, but POST certain values to the handle.php script @guru